# why we need to use const reference as arguments to thread functions

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety

When I use "int &x" in Modify_X,  then I get below error, but if I use const int &x, then the program works fine. What is the difference between these 2 scenarios.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
    int x;
    public:
    Test():x(110){}
    void Modify_X(int & x)
    {
       cout<<"address of x = "<<&x<<endl;
       x = x+10;
       cout<<"after modify x = "<<x<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test t1;
    int y = 30;
    thread t_obj(Test::Modify_X, t1, y));
    t_obj.join();
    cout<<"address of y = "<<&y<<endl;
    cout<<"value of y = "<<y<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Error: static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues